# Shock Mount - Why use elastic?

Tags: engineering, microphone-stand

Why do shock mounts use elasticated cord (which can perish) to the exclusion of other materials? Why not use coil springs?

Especially since the cord, being strung point to point around the mount, constitutes a single point of failure. Why not the more robust steel, with greater redundancy?

Perhaps I'm making a mountain from a molehill, but I'm perplexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coil springs go 'boing' ;-)
Elastic doesn't.

Seriously, metal springing will transmit noise where elastic will damp it much more quickly. Fabric-wrapped elastic even more so, as the fabric aids the damping process. For a silly comparison, try twanging an elastic band under tension, then the top of your underpants ;)

Undamped springs would keep moving a long time after fabric-coated elastic will have stopped.

Comment: Oh! That makes sense, and I'd totally overlooked the damping effect of the fabric. Thank you!

Comment: Additionally, without even more engineering, rubber or plastic hole grommets etc, where each spring hooked on, there would be potential for creaking. Basically, elastic 'just works' & has done for decades.